# Help with basic syllogism

Tags: logic

'If A does not belong to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A'

When I draw 'if A does not belong to some B' out, I get two partially overlapping circles, A and B, where some A is not B and some B is not A. However, the second half of the statement, 'It is not necessary that B should not belong to some A' would imply that the part of circle A outside of B is not present, correct? Does 'it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A' mean 'it is necessary that B should belong to B'? Is there another way of showing that the statement is true with Euler diagrams?

Comment: Why "two separate conclusions" ?

Comment: "There are some Humans that are not Philosopher": TRUE. "There are some Philosophers that are not Humans": FALSE.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: The short answer is to draw a proper subset.

Comment: The language here seems broken.  What on earth does 'some' mean here?  If "A does not belong to some B" is to choose a random B, then A is bound and we cannot later choose 'some A'.  Can you make sure you have the statement correct?

Comment: @hide_in_plain_sight - "language broken" ? What does it mean ? "What does 'some' mean here?" "Some" means *some*, i.e. not all. "A does not belong to some B" means that there are objects (i.e. *subjects*) that are A and are **not** B i.e. such that the *predicate* A applies to them while the *predicate* B does not.

Comment: See my example above : "There are some Humans that are not Philosopher". There are creatures to whom the predicate "Humanity" (B) applies while the predicate "Philosopher" (A) does not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  'Some country' cannot *ever* be the capital city of an identified country. Ever.  It is instead a previously unidentified country. 'Some of a country' can mean that, but the sentence does not say that.  So this is not English, the grammar is broken.  And 'A does not belong to B' implies A is a single object, not a set, much less a predicate.    So 'some' means *some* is just false.

Comment: If the answers below is enough for you, please accept it and we can "close" the post.

Comment: If a person (A) does not belong to some dog (B), it is not necessary that the dog should not belong to the person.

Answer (score 0):

How you are understanding the question is that the circles overlap which called a [Euler diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram). In which case, there are three possible drawings:

1. The two circles DO NOT overlap
2. They PARTIALLY overlap
3. They COMPLETELY overlap.

(1) If they DO NOT overlap, all that belong to A do not belong to B and vice versa, or alternatively something can belong to A or B but not both. (∃x:x∈A⊻x∈B)

(3) If they COMPLETELY overlap, all that belong to A belong to B, or alternatively all that belong to B belong to A, or alternatively all that belong to either belong to both. (∃x:x∈A∧x∈B)

and to your question:

(2) If they PARTIALLY overlap, some that belong to A belong to B and some do not, and some that belong to B belong to A and some do not, or alternatively, some belong to only A, only B, or only to both A and B. (∃x:(x∈A∧x∉B)⊻(x∉A∧x∈B)⊻(x∈A∧x∈B))

You believe that the last is the case implied by the question, however, it is not the only case!

4. If two circles PARTIALLY overlap, either neither contains the other since both partially contain the other but not COMPLETELY or one contains the other completely. If one contains the other AND they overlap but not COMPLETELY, then one PROPERLY CONTAINS the other.

Thus, instead of drawing two circles overlapping delineating three regions since the two circles proper intersect at two points, you can draw two circles so their regions overlap by having one circle entirely inside the region of another with no intersection of the circles proper at all. In plainspeak just draw one circle entirely inside the other. Two concentric circles of different diameters would be an example.

Therefore:

> 'If A does not belong to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A'

This can be rephrased as 'some A are not B, but all B are A'. It can be a special case that there exists A in B, but no B outside of A because ALL B are members of A and B does not exhaust A. This is called a proper subset. (∃x:(x∈A∧x∉B)⊻(x∈A∧x∈B))

REFERENCES:

- [WP:Square of Opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition)
- [WP:Subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset)

RESPONSE TO COMMENT, 2020-02-11

> How come for "if A does not belongs [sic] to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A' one circle contains the other, whereas for 'if A belongs to some B, it is necessary for B to belong to some A' the circles partially overlap? Why is one a circle within another circle and one a partially overlapping circle, when the language is so similar?

[image: Four Cases]

Okay, I should have gone with a pic the first time, but I'm lazy. The language is difficult but gleeful for logicians because we don't use the double negative in English normally. The type of situation that makes [ordinary language philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_language_philosophy) groan. Let's unpack the image.

"If A does not belong to some B", then Case 1 is NOT possible. So we can rule it out. That leaves three cases. In Case 4, "If A does not belong to some B", it IS necessary that B should not belong to some A. So far, so good. But, it is ALSO true, that "it is NOT necessary that B should not belong to some A" because we have Cases 2 and 3. In fact, with Case 2 we can say if "A does not belong to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A" because it is POSSIBLE by S3 that A can B. But that might be confusing, so let's look at Case 3. This is the definitive case because if "A does not belong to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A" because it is IMPOSSIBLE that B does not belong to A.

So to review, "if A does not belong to some B" (S2, S5, S7; x∈A∧x∉B) such as in Cases 2, 3, and 4, we have three possibilities:

- Either "it IS necessary that B should not belong to some A" (x∈B∧x∉A) which is only Case 4 since any B can't be A.
- Or B might or might not belong to A (S3⊻S4; (x∈B∧x∉A)⊻(x∈B∧x∈A)) as in Case 2 because the B has regions in and out of A
- Or it is necessary that B SHOULD belong to some A" (S6; x∈B∧x∈A) which is Case 3.

Ergo, "If A does not belong to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A".

The key is working back from the non-double negative version of the statement which makes this statement almost incomprehensible!

Comment: I'm having a problem with the language.
How come for "if A does not belongs to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A' one circle contains the other,
whereas for 'if A belongs to some B, it is necessary for B to belong to some A' the circles partially overlap? 
Why is one a circle within another circle and one a partially overlapping circle, when the language is so similar?

Comment: @DengLin I've given it another shot. If you have further questions, let me know, and I'll refine.

Comment: @J D for case 3, shouldn't B be the outer circle and A be the inner? Also, what do you mean by 'with Case 2 we can say if "A does not belong to some B, it is not necessary that B should not belong to some A" because it is POSSIBLE by S3 that A can B'?

Comment: @JD You are confusing Venn diagrams  with Euler diagrams. What you explained is Euler diagram.  Venn diagrams were named after John Venn who was a philosopher. There are no circles within other circles in Vem diagrams which is what you did. Venn diagrams always has the same diagram. These do not depend on the types of premises as you would worry about Euler diagrams. All arguments have 3 overlapping circles regardless of the premises. Venn diagrams use the same diagram for all syllogisms. Euler diagrams vary on the argument.

Comment: @Logikal Thank you for bringing this to my attention.